# How to print all lines of responses of command in telnet?

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, printing, telnet

Perhaps this is trivial but Google searching doesn't find anything useful at all.

I am using Windows 10, and I use `telnet.exe` to control my modem.

Sometimes the responses of the commands entered is way too long, the text spans many lines, and the response is truncated.

I absolutely have no idea what this is called, and this is why I am asking.

Because the text is so long, all lines are printed one by one in quick succession in a fixed viewport, the printing is practically instant, meaning I cannot see the text while it is printing.

The lines are printed inside a fixed box, old lines are overwritten by new lines, or pushed outside of the box by the new lines.

Whatever is the case, the box has fixed height and can only display fixed number of lines. The box therefore only displays the latest lines that fits into the box, the older text is outside of the view and there is no way to scroll.

So I can only see a small part of the response.

How can I make it so that the terminal displays the whole response line by line without bounds, so that I can see full response?

Comment: Can you pipe the output to a variable you can then view later? What terminal are you using? Have you adjusted the terminal's size and number of lines stored and cached? These are the common ways of doing this.